# Deploying Mono applications to Windows

Tags: windows, mono, cross-platform

What difficulty would be encountered in deploying a Mono-based application to Windows?
Does the Mono runtime have to be installed along with the application?  Would this be an inconvenience for the end user?

**Edit:**  The idea is to deploy a cross-platform application, thus Mono as a choice.

Answer (score 4):

Mono is an implementation of .NET. As long as you don't use Mono-specific APIs, it should be 100% compatible.

Comment: ...and as long as you don't use APIs that Mono hasn't implemented.

Comment: @Broam If you use Mono-incompatible APIs, then it wouldn't work on Mono in the first place.

Comment: The original question stated cross-platform, which means both sides' incompatibility have to be considered[

Answer (score 1):

As [@duffymo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/37213/duffymo) said you are probably better off requiring .NET vs requiring Mono. However, there are some scenarios where using Mono makes sense. In particular, if you use [mkbundle](http://www.mono-project.com/Guide:Running_Mono_Applications) to create an assembly without a requirement that Mono is installed. There is even a way to statically link the runtime into the exe although this brings along some licensing requirements that need to be considered.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're sticking to managed code in your application and the there is either .NET or Mono installed, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If Mono is a Linux version of .NET, wouldn't deploying an app developed on Linux with Mono on Windows simply mean taking your source/package and deploying it on Windows?  Shouldn't the .NET pieces that need to be common already be available on Windows?

Comment: GTK# is not available on Windows by default, but a *lot* of Mono programs use it.

Comment: @Broam - True, but GTK# is easily installable as a .NET library on Windows so you do not need Mono to use GTK# - http://ftp.novell.com/pub/mono/gtk-sharp/gtk-sharp-2.12.10.win32.msi